# Running Count of active users over time in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to calculate the number of active (activity in last 90 days) users on Tableau and display it in a chart over time.

I was able to calculate it for a single date, but am unable to make it change over time:

```
COUNTD( IF dt > today() -90 and activity>0 then cust_id end )
```

Comment: Try this method. https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C5vANSAZ/running-total-with-a-count-distinct

Comment: That method just adds up all active users in the month and does not account for when users stop being active. Hope that clarifies this a bit more.